# I am moving a large static library from Windows to Linux

Tags: shared-library

I am moving a large static library from Windows to Linux.  To make it worse, I am new to Linux.  All the examples I've found tell me how to construct libraries with so few object files all the names will fit on one line.  What do I do if the library contains a few hundred files?

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; this isn't a Linux support site (SE *Unix & Linux* covers that), but a Ubuntu site. Are you asking about Ubuntu Core? , Ubuntu Server? or Ubuntu Desktop?  as *apps* run *confined* in Core systems don't have access to your root file-system, so rules can vary on product, of which you gave no specifics.

Comment: I have no idea what this is about. Please edit your question and add some context. Indicate more concisely and specifically what you try to do, what you want to achieve and what does not work according to your expectations. Also provide information about the Ubuntu version you use (the command `lsb_release -a` will tell you) and the desktop environment (standard Ubuntu version or a flavor like Kubuntu, Xubuntu?)

Comment: The standard way to split input across lines (both in shell commands and inside Makefiles) uses the backslash as a line continuation character. You really shouldn't have an issue with this until the total length exceeds the kernel's ARG_MAX or MAX_ARG_STRLEN limits.